# Typescript when a field in return is null, manage this case

Tags: angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I have this code :

```
const { name, company = {} as Company } = this.company;
const { id: id, name: nameOfCompany } = company;
if (id && nameOfCompany) {}
```

And I get the message : `TypeError: "company is null"`, how I can manage that in a proper way ?

Comment: Use a null guard for `company`? You can do `if(company)` or even something like `const { id: id, name: nameOfCompany } = company || {}`. The part `company = {} as Company ` in the destructuring assignment would only work if the `company` key is missing or equal to `undefined`.

Comment: The error is in this if :(

Comment: The error happens as part of the destructuring assignment `const { id: id, name: nameOfCompany } = company;` because `company` is null (as the message says), so you cannot get the `id` or `name` from `null`. You have to handle it *before* this.